# Return static vector by reference is slow

Tags: c++, c++11, return-by-reference

I was setting up a cache to draw some shapes. My approach was as following:

I created a class OrbitCacheManager.h that looked like this:

```
#ifndef OrbitCacheManager_h
#define OrbitCacheManager_h
#include <vector>
#include "cache_0_0.h"
#include "cache_1_0.h"
// many more includes

namespace Core {

   class OrbitCacheManager
   {
   public:
        static std::pair<float,float> getValue(const std::pair<int,int>& type, float phase, float param)
        {
            auto cache = getCacheData(type);
            // interpolate values based on phase and param
            return calculated_value;
        }
   private:
        static std::vector<std::pair<float,float>>& getCacheData(const std::pair<int,int>& type)
        {
            if (type.first == 0 && type.second == 0) return cache_0_0::values;
            if (type.first == 1 && type.second == 0) return cache_1_0::values;
            // etc
        }
```

The cache files look like this:

**cache_0_0.h**:

```
#ifndef cache_0_0_h
#define cache_0_0_h 
#include <vector>
namespace Core {
class cache_0_0{
public:
    static std::vector<std::pair<float,float>> values;
};
};
#endif
```

**cache_0_0.cpp**:

```
#include "cache_0_0.h"
using namespace Core;
std::vector<std::pair<float,float>> cache_0_0::values = {
{ 0.000000, 1.000000 },     { 0.062791, 0.998027 }, // etc
```

This was ment to be run like this:

```
for (some phase range) {
    auto v = OrbitCacheManager::getValue(type, phase, param);
    // do something with v
}
```

This approach turn out really slow, the profiler showed lots of CPU peaks and the UI was really laggy.

When I refactored the getCacheData method in OrbitCacheManager.h to this:

```
static std::vector<std::pair<float,float>>* getCacheData(const std::pair<int,int>& type) 
{
    if (type.first == 0 && type.second == 0) return &(cache_0_0::values);
```

Everything started working as expected.

My question is, why did that change increased speed so dramatically?

I'am using clang c++11 on IOS

Comment: You should state what the compiler options you used to compile your code.  If you are running unoptimized code, the timings you're showing are meaningless.

Comment: There was similar question of using `auto` vs `auto &`  in a for range loop, maybe not a dup but could be related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be returning it by reference, but you are storing in another object, hence still doing a costly copy:

```
 auto& cache = getCacheData(type);
```

You should add the `&` everywhere you return by reference and expect to keep a reference and not a copy.

Comment: @NathanOliver added a note for the reference and fixed the answer.

Comment: Yes, it was that! I thought that auto already had the reference.

Comment: `auto` may capture the const, but it doesn't capture the `&`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `auto` without a reference doesn't capture `const` either. It uses exactly the same rules as template argument decuction.

Comment: @Angew `const std::vector<int>& get()` can be captured by `auto&`, you don't need the `const`, so it is captured in this case.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, `auto &` can become `const T &`, but plain `auto` will never become a `const T`. I found the comment somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Angew Agreed, that's definitely true.